# Authorizing broadcasting channel in an SPA

Tags: php, laravel, single-page-application, laravel-echo

My project is divided into two apps: vue based client-side app and laravel based server-side rest api app. I have uncommented `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,` in the `config/app.php` file.

The default broadcasting authorization route is, `/broadcasting/auth`. Since it has a `web` middleware applied, it shows a 419 due to CSRF issue. So in the `BroadcastServiceProvider` I changed this:

```
Broadcast::routes();
```

to this:

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
```

But now the problem is whenever I visit my client-side app, I get the following error in the console:

> GET http://localhost:8000/v1/login 405 (Method Not Allowed)

How do I fix this?

My client side configuration:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth',
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'anyKey',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true
});

window.Echo.private('test.1').listen('TestUpdated', (e) => {
    /*eslint-disable no-console*/
    console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing in my `api.php` routes file:

```
Route::post('/broadcast',function (Request $request){
    $pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'), env('PUSHER_APP_ID'));
    return $pusher->socket_auth($request->request->get('channel_name'),$request->request->get('socket_id'));
});
```

Then I changed the `authEndpoint` to that route in the client-side app:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/broadcast',
    ...
}
```