# Laravel Echo not subscribing to Pusher Presence Channel, not even in Pusher dashboard

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo, pusher-js

I have spend many hours to solve this issue of mine, reading the doc multiple times, googling here and there: SO, Laracast, Larachat, etc, but still couldn't get Laravel Echo to subscribe to Pusher presence channel, and **it doesn't show any error in console tab**

> **Public** and **Private** channel are working fine and smooth, users can subscribe, users can listen / trigger event(s)

> **Note**: before creation of this post, I have search questions related to my current issue, **none of them have answer**

Some questions similar to mine:

- https://laravelquestions.com/2020/12/15/laravel-echo-not-joining-presence-channel-in-production/
- [Laravel Echo + Laravel Passport auth in private / presence websockets channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147925/laravel-echo-laravel-passport-auth-in-private-presence-websockets-channels?rq=1)
- https://laravel.io/forum/facing-issues-upon-subscribing-to-presence-channel
- etc..

Spec:

- Laravel: `7.30.1`
- laravel-Echo: `1.10.0` (latest; atm)
- pusher/pusher-php-server: `4.0`
- pusher-js: `7.0.3` (latest; atm)

In `resource/js/bootstrap.js`

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    authEndpoint: '/api/broadcasting/auth',
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage['token']}`
        }
    }    
});
```

In `routes/api.php`

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55555844/authorizing-broadcasting-channel-in-an-spa
Route::post('/broadcasting/auth', function (Request $request) {
    $pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
        env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER')
        ]
    );

    // This will return JSON response: {auth:"__KEY__"}, see comment below
    // https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users
    $response = $pusher->socket_auth($request->request->get('channel_name'), $request->request->get('socket_id'));

    return $response;
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

In `routes/channels.php`

```
// https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#authorizing-presence-channels
Broadcast::channel('whatever', function ($user) {
    return [
        'id' => $user->id,
        'name' => $user->name
    ];
});
```

In `home.vue`

```
...
...
created() {
    Echo.join('whatever') // DOES NOT WORK, Even in mounted() vue lifehook, and in Pusher dashboard, it doesn't show this channel name
        .here((users) => {
            console.table(users)
        })
}
```

> Q: Why Laravel Echo not subscribing to Pusher presence channel? and even in Pusher, it doesn't show channel name: `presence-whatever`, only `disconnected` (after I refreshed the page) and then `connected` like **nothing happen**

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what's your event's `broadcastOn()` function?

Comment: Hi, **public channel and private channel are working fine**, the problem is: I'm tyring to subscribe on presence channel, but it's not working like any tutorial / doc, I'm not sending any data, just **want to subscribe to presence channel**

Answer (score 1):

**1. Make sure to set the broadcast driver to .env after that do php artisan** config:clear
`BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher`

**2. Ferify your auth.php. I have like this**

[image]

**3. Check your `broadcasting.php`** this is my dev config

[image]

**4. Check CORS settings** I installed `fruitcake/laravel-cors` and this is my `cors.php` config
[image]

Maybe for you `supports_credentials` need to be `true`

**5. Check your `channels.php`**. I have

[image]

Comment: Hi maxim, I thank you for the answer, but unfortunately, atm my pc is broken and need to be fixed, at least 2 week, but don't worry, after my pc got fixed, I will re-open the bounty and test your answer, if it works, I will check your answer as the correct one, again, I'm sorry and please wait for my pc to be fixed

Comment: Hello maxim, I just tested your answer on my friend's PC, and it's not working

Comment: @ChristianDelvianto there are some errors?
Also in channels.php you probably need to return user data or false (if access denied)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the broadcast driver to env after that do `php artisan config:clear`

Use `window.Echo.channel('whatever')` to join the channel.

Comment: **Public and private channel are working fine**, the problem is, user are not subscribing to presence channel

Comment: Hi @musti, I'm trying to subscribe to `presence channel`, not sending any data tho, normally, without any route for channel in `routes/channel.php` we can subscribe to a channel / multiple channel, as long as we have syntax in our code like: `Echo.channel('public')` or `Echo.private('private')`, and **we can see in Pusher dashboard that we are subscribing to channel(s)**, I have tested it, and it's working for me, in terms: **`public`** and **`private`** channel

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue and was stuck for hours.
I changed 'useTLS' to FALSE in config/broadcasting.php and magically got it working.